# Destructure JavaScript array to computed property names of existing object

Tags: javascript, destructuring

### Problem

Say we have an array of values:

```
const values = [ 10, 20, 30 ];
```

Say we have an object that we want to pick up these values:

```
let props = {
    "hello": null,
    "world": null,
    "other": null
};
```

I could simply do this:

```
props.hello = values[0];
props.world = values[1];
props.other = values[2];
```

That way we'd end up with the desired result:

```
console.log(props.hello); // Result: 10
console.log(props.world); // Result: 20
console.log(props.other); // Result: 30
```

Or, more accurately:

```
console.log(props);
// Result:
// {
//      "hello": 10,
//      "world": 20,
//      "other": 30
// }
```

The problem is I don't always know what the names of the properties will need to be.

Suppose `props` is an existing but empty object (or if it does contain properties, they are unrelated to what we're doing here).

```
props = {};
```

And suppose we want to compute the name of each property from some related value.

How can I populate `props` with the names and values I want?

### One solution

So I could do this instead, reducing an array of names to an object and then assigning that object's properties back to the original object:

```
const names = [ "hello", "world", "other" ];
const newProps = names.reduce((p, c, i) => {
    p[c] = values[i];
    return p;
}, {});

props = Object.assign({}, props, newProps);
```

But this seems messy. For one, it assumes that for every `i` that exists in `values` the equivalent would exist for `names`.

### Question

Is there a way to do this with a destructuring assignment?

Yes, there is if I know the names of the properties beforehand:

```
[ props.hello, props.world, props.other ] = values;
```

But what if the names exist separately or need to be calculated before they can be assigned to the `props` object?

```
let props = {};
const values = [ 10, 20, 30 ];
const names = [ "hello", "world", "other" ];
// [ ...props??? ] = values;
//
// Desired result (props):
// {
//      "hello": 10,
//      "world": 20,
//      "other": 30
// }
```

One other thing: The reason I'm interested in destructuring, apart from the conciseness of the form, is that I'd like `names` and `values` to be considered "immutable" once declared. The object `props` would ideally be the only changing state in the code. (I've hinted at this by declaring `names` and `values` with `const`, and `props` with `let`, although I know in practice these declarations don`t stop the contents of objects and arrays from being changed.)

Comment: `const props = Object.fromEntries(names.map((name, i) => [name, values[i]]))` Not using destructuring, but would work. I don't think destructuring alone could do this

Comment: You imply that `values[i]` might not exist. With that precondition, how would you expect any form of array destructuring to work in the first place?

Comment: @blex Thanks. Yes, your line of code is a version of my reduce function (although more concise). I suspect you're right that it's not possible with destructuring alone but wanted to throw the question out there in case somebody had figured out a way.

Comment: @str I probably need to articulate this better. I suppose I don't like the assumption that because `i` necessarily exists in `names`, it would also exist in `values`. Destructuring allows for default values where the property doesn't exist but also has a rest operator for properties that do but might not otherwise be captured. It seems like a neater way to handle this... _if_ it's even possible.

Comment: @str With any luck, the question is a little clearer now.

Comment: Also added point about state as one of the answers helpfully made me realise this was missing.

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate the names and values at the same time for assignment.

```js
let values = [10, 20, 30],
    props = {},
    names = ["hello", "world", "other"];

for (props[names.shift()] of values) ;

console.log(props);
```

Another thinkable solution, but with hardcoded object reference.

```js
let values = [10, 20, 30],
    props = {},
    names = ["hello", "world", "other"];

[props[names.shift()], props[names.shift()], props[names.shift()]] = values;

console.log(props);
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting solution and you're right that this "iterates" both structures at the same time, albeit by changing the `names` array as you go. The question was more about doing this with a destructuring assignment. I was hoping to avoid changes to state like altering the original array -- I'll try to make that clearer in the question.

Comment: I've added that point about changing and state to the question now. Thanks for your answer -- it helped me to better refine what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The expected result could be obtained as follows:

```js
let values = [ 10, 20, 30 ];
let names = [ "hello", "world", "other" ];
let props = {};

names.forEach((name, index) => props[name] = values[index]);
console.log(props);
```